# how to integrate my simple python nlp script into my rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, nlp, svm, data-science

I wrote a python script which automatically categorizes set of articles. I want to integrate it into my rails app.Please let me know if anybody has the approach.Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use this gem: https://github.com/halostatue/rubypython to import python script inside a ruby module and play around with it. Having said that your question should include the efforts you have made till now. please go through this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks.I have been playing with my python script to achieving the good accuracy.I got a decent accuracy.so i want to integrate my python script to my rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this gem: github.com/halostatue/rubypython to import python script inside a ruby module and play around with it. for rails you can create a module inside concerns(`article_concern.rb`) may be and call `rubypython` there something like this:

```
module ArticleConcern
  require "rubypython"
  :
  :
end
```